# Trigger no funciona por no pasar por el CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Tengo una tabla Datos en la que tengo un Trigger que se lanza después de insertar datos. Cuando trato de insertar un dato con valores que no pasan por ningún CASE, rompe, y no me deja insertar nada. Investigando pone que debería usar un ELSE para cuando no pase por ninguna de las opciones anteriormente establecidas, pero me da un error de sintaxis. ¿Cómo puedo solventarlo?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`aaronibio`@`%` TRIGGER `datos_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `datos` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    # declares
    DECLARE current_id INT;
    DECLARE tem_max DOUBLE;
    DECLARE tem_min DOUBLE;
    DECLARE hum_max DOUBLE;
    DECLARE hum_min DOUBLE;
    DECLARE luz_max DOUBLE;
    
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM especie_terrario WHERE idterrario = NEW.idterrario) > 0 THEN
        # inserts   
        SELECT idusuario, temperatura_minima, temperatura_maxima, humedad_minima, humedad_maxima, horas_luz INTO current_id, tem_min, tem_max, hum_min, hum_max, luz_max FROM terrarios WHERE id = NEW.idterrario LIMIT 1;
    
        # checks
        CASE
            WHEN NEW.temperatura < tem_min THEN
                INSERT INTO notificacion (idterrario, fecha, texto) VALUES (NEW.idterrario, NOW(), "El terrario está por debajo de su temperatura mínima. Riesgo alto. Algunas especies podrían morir.");
            WHEN NEW.temperatura = tem_min THEN
                INSERT INTO notificacion (idterrario, fecha, texto) VALUES (NEW.idterrario, NOW(), "El terrario está muy frío.");
            WHEN NEW.temperatura = tem_max THEN
                INSERT INTO notificacion (idterrario, fecha, texto) VALUES (NEW.idterrario, NOW(), "El terrario está muy caliente.");
            WHEN NEW.temperatura > tem_max THEN
                INSERT INTO notificacion (idterrario, fecha, texto) VALUES (NEW.idterrario, NOW(), "El terrario está por encima de su temperatura máxima. Riesgo alto. Algunas especies podrían morir.");
                IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuario_logro WHERE idusuario = current_id AND idlogro = 4) = 0 THEN
                    INSERT INTO usuario_logro (idusuario, idlogro, fecha_adquisicion) VALUES (current_id, 4, NOW());
                END IF;
            ELSE # aqui el error de sintaxis. Sin ello, no puedo insertar datos correctamente.
                
            END CASE;
         
         CASE
         WHEN NEW.humedad < hum_min THEN
            INSERT INTO notificacion (idterrario, fecha, texto) VALUES (NEW.idterrario, NOW(), "El terrario está por debajo de su humedad mínima. Riesgo alto. Algunas especies podrían morir.");
         WHEN NEW.humedad = hum_min THEN
            INSERT INTO notificacion (idterrario, fecha, texto) VALUES (NEW.idterrario, NOW(), "El terrario está muy seco.");
         WHEN NEW.humedad = hum_max THEN
            INSERT INTO notificacion (idterrario, fecha, texto) VALUES (NEW.idterrario, NOW(), "El terrario está muy húmedo.");
        WHEN NEW.humedad > hum_max THEN
            INSERT INTO notificacion (idterrario, fecha, texto) VALUES (NEW.idterrario, NOW(), "El terrario está por encima de la humedad máxima. Riesgo algo. Algunas especies podrían ahogarse.");
            IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuario_logro WHERE idusuario = current_id AND idlogro = 5) = 0 THEN
                INSERT INTO usuario_logro (idusuario, idlogro, fecha_adquisicion) VALUES (current_id, 5,  NOW());
            END IF;
        END CASE;
        
         IF NEW.luz = 10 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuario_logro WHERE idusuario = current_id AND idlogro = 6) = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO usuario_logro (idusuario, idlogro, fecha_adquisicion) VALUES (current_id, 6,  NOW());
        END IF;
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Tu error es meter un `IF` dentro de un `CASE`, en vez del `IF`, usa otro `CASE` anidado. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537920/5587982).

Comment: Tratando de anidar un CASE en vez del IF me está dando error de sintaxis igualmente... Estoy perdidísimo aquí...

Comment: Saludos. Prueba lo siguiente; las instrucciones que están entre el `WHEN NEW.temperatura > tem_max THEN` y el `ELSE` _(que indicas te marca el error)_ colócalas dentro de un `BEGIN...END`

Comment: La forma de hacerlo es esa, no puedes meter un `IF` dentro de un `CASE`. Plantea en papel y lápiz la lógica decisional, te ayudará a aclararte si estás perdido e incluso te ayudará a simplificar quizá. A veces uno se hace un lío con las decisiones precisamente por no pensarlo en frío, sobre papel y lápiz, lejos del código, que a veces ofusca.

Comment: CASE es una expresión, no es una instrucción. CASE debe de existir dentro de una instrucción y no al revés.